# TCPDF - writeHTML - Table with images

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using writeHTML to output a HTML table with a foto.
This is the code I have:

```
    <?php
require_once('config/lang/por.php');
require_once('tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetMargins(1, 5, 1);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///---///

$pdf->AddPage();

$tablebi = "<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=\"60\">  Foto </td>
        <td colspan=\"60\"> Item & Colour</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 34</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 35</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 36</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 37</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 38</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 39</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 40</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 41</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 42</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 43</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 44</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 45</td>
        <td colspan=\"16\"> Total</td>
        <td colspan=\"16\"> Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=270><hr width=100%></hr></td></tr> <tr>
        <td colspan=\"60\" rowspan=\"1\">  131-A4550 <img src=\"../stimages/Thumbnails/nofoto.jpg\" border=0 border=\"0\" /> </td>
        <td colspan=\"60\">  <p>PRETO </p></td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 1</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 1</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"16\" align=center> <b>2</b></td>
        <td colspan=\"16\" align=right> 0.00 &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=\"60\" rowspan=\"1\">  131-A4551 <img src=\"../stimages/Thumbnails/nofoto.jpg\" border=0 border=\"0\" /> </td>
        <td colspan=\"60\">  <p>PRETO </p></td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 1</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"10\"> 0</td>
        <td colspan=\"16\" align=center> <b>1</b></td>
        <td colspan=\"16\" align=right> 0.00 &euro;</td>
    </tr> </table>  ";

// Dados das linhas da grelha principal
$pdf->setxy(11, 73);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 6);
$pdf->writeHTML($tablebi, true, false, false, false, '');

$pdf->Output('uuuuu0', 'I');
?>
```

The space between the rows that I have the images have a huge gap.
How can I present this table without all this space between these two rows.

Check out the image of the generated PDF here (http://jmamede.com/forum/tcpdfhelp001.png)

Comment: what is up with all those colspans? you specify a total column count of 272 in your first row, 542 in the second, and 272 in the third. and don't have anywhere NEAR that number of actual columns...

Comment: I think you don't know what are the colspan and rowspan... there's no reason to use them like this. for your picture, you can give size for have a smaller image.

Comment: I used the rowspan because in that line, after the ITEM&COLOUR column, I might have more than 1 line. The photo is the same (it is a shoe), but i can have more colours in different sizes.

Comment: I use the colspan to set a specific colums width. I could not fins another way to set the width of a column with TCPDF :(